# launch python script in another xterm session

Tags: python, xterm

This line of code has my stymied.  I've read about many ways to launch a python script in a new terminal window.  I think I'm very close with this statement but it seems to be choking on my path.

the line of code is:

```
os.system("xterm -hold 'sudo python /home/pi/newcode/newcode/hms2-v2.5.py'")
```

the error message is:

```
xterm: no absolute path found for shell: sudo python /home/pi/newcode/newcode/hms2-v2.5.py
```

Answer (score 2):

It's telling you the truth.  When you run `xterm <thing>`, `xterm` will try to find a binary named `<thing>` in your `$PATH`.  In this case, you've passed a long quoted string but it's still a single argument and `xterm` is predictably failing to find it.

For what you're trying to do you need the `-e` option. From the man page:

```
   -e program [ arguments ... ]
           This option specifies the program (and its command line arguments) to be run in the xterm window.  It also sets
           the window title and icon name to be the basename of the program being executed if neither -T nor -n are given on
           the command line.
```

So:

```
os.system("xterm -hold -e sudo python /home/pi/newcode/newcode/hms2-v2.5.py")
```

Comment: I struggled with that for hours.  I had the '-e' option at one point, but before the -hold option. The program it is launching has errors because the files it works with now have a different path.  I'm guessing I need to edit my code to include full absolute paths for the files i works with?

Answer (score 1):

```
subprocess.Popen(['xterm', '-e', 'bash -c \"python pythonFile.py; exec bash\"'])
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for the code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A proper explanation would greatly improve its [long-term value](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by describing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

As noted, you should use the [**`-e`** option](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#OPTIONS:-e):

> **`-e`** *program [ arguments ... ]*
>                  This option specifies the program (and its command line
>                  arguments) to be run in the xterm window.  It also sets the
>                  window title and icon name to be the basename of the program
>                  being executed if neither -T nor -n are given on the command
>                  line.
>   **NOTE**: This must be the **last option** on the command line.

There's a subtle point in the manual page: when you omit the **`-e`**, xterm tries to interpret the whole quoted string as the name of a shell interpreter.  That's indirectly due to the way it implements the [*localFilter*](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#VT100-Widget-Resources:localeFilter):

> When using a locale-filter, e.g., with the **`-e`** option, or the
>                  shell, xterm first tries passing control via that filter.  If
>                  it fails, xterm will retry without the locale-filter.  Xterm
>                  warns about the failure before retrying.

There's some additional discussion at the beginning of the [*OPTIONS*](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#h2-OPTIONS) section:

> One parameter (after all options) may be given.  That overrides xterm's
>          built-in choice of shell program:
>
> - If the parameter is not a relative path, i.e., beginning with "./" or
>          "../", xterm looks for the file in the user's PATH.  In either case,
>          this check fails if xterm cannot construct an absolute path.

So... when you tried

```
os.system("xterm -hold 'sudo python /home/pi/newcode/newcode/hms2-v2.5.py'")
```

xterm tried finding a program named

```
sudo python /home/pi/newcode/newcode/hms2-v2.5.py
```

which was not what you intended.